# Does Next.js SSG support dyamic data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am making a webapp using Next.js and have a question regarding the Static generated sites. My webapp is a blog, and requires a path for each blog entry in the database. If I were to statically generate my webapp and host it on Vercel, would the `getStaticPaths` function update the paths when a new entry is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how are you adding new entries. If your are adding it as new file on your project and each time you add a new entry you deploy your whole site too, then yes, each time you re-deploy your site your `paths` will be updated.

If you're using some CMS or another way to add new entries that doesn't re-deploy your site to each time you add new content, what you can do is set the `fallback` option to `true` or `"blocking"` depending on what you prefer. [Fallback Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required). This will search for all the routes that were not generated at build time before trigger a 404 (All the new entries).

Now, you probably want to use it along with `revalidate` on the `getStaticProps` of your post page. This because if you go to a route before you create that post, it will trigger a 404 and this 404 it wont be updated or regenerated until you re-build your site. You can use `revalidate` to fix this by setting an amount of time you want to re-generate that page without having to re-build or re-deploy the whole site.

On the [Incremental Static Regeneration Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) they use an example pretty similar to yours, you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

To generate new page after the build you need to set fallback as true in the return object of your `getStaticPaths` function. [More here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-true).